# Django - 404 static files not found

Tags: python, django

I know theres about a millon of these questions but non of them have helped me out.

I can't access my static files for deployment, I've slpit my settings file into base and production and put them in a folder in the settings.py orginal file.

I've done everything neccessary but it still doesn't seem to be working and I can't work it out for the life of me.

I've tried editing the path several time and no change.

Maybe I've missed something obvious and someone else can see it.

1. venv
2. --project
3. ----app1
4. ------static folder
5. ----wsgi folder
6. ------settings_old.py
7. ------new settings folder
8. ---------base.py
9. ---------production.py

base.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles',]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_r')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

I've tried a couple of different things like changing from BASE_DIR to a new PROD_DIR that directly goes to the static file in index.

```
PROD_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__' ))
PROD_ROOT= os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__' ))))
PROD_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
```

Nothing seems to be working.

UPDATE:

as suggested by other I've tried collectstatic, the folder env/project/static_r was found however, i get

> '0 files where copied to static_r'.

furthermore, also as suggested I printed out base_dir and prod_dir and got the following

> "prod is /user/venv/project" & "base is /user/venv/project/wsgi-folder"

p.s this is after I edited prod_dir to -

```
PROD_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__' ))
```

Comment: Have you entered your virtual environ (or do you use one) and ran `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: him why do you have `BASE_DIR` with two `dirname` functions? Is the problem maybe there?

Comment: @JanSila because base.py is another directory lower than the original settings.py, however i have tried it with only one and it still didnt work

Comment: @MattCremeens I haven't ran collectstatic yet but it should work based on the STATIC_DIR but regardless i'll check now and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure, but are you sure it is STATIC_DIRS and not STATICFILES_DIRS? '-'

Comment: OMFG YOUR AN ABSOLUTE ANGEL sir/madam. I've literally been pulling my hair out the last 36 hours. I appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: It's ok :) It already happened to me, i had STATICFILES_DIR instead of STATICFILES_DIRS and I really didn't know which was my error xD

Answer (score 0):

Based on your settings, your static files should be located in /project/static/ instead of in the individual app.

You will also need to load the static files as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/)

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

Comment: Yes i've loaded the static files in using the tag

Answer (score 0):

What you can always do to test your paths is to print it.

so in your settings do

```
print BASE_DIR, STATIC_DIRS, STATIC_ROOT
```

and you'll see where your error is.

In my opinion it's the fact you're putting the static folder within the app, rather than within the project, because `collectstatic` will put all static files in one directory regardless

Comment: Cheers for the idea, I've done it and updated the question